# Test cases for Redhat OpenStack?

Tags: python, cloud, integration-testing, redhat, openstack

I am working in **RedHat OpenStack** project and I need to know good test cases for reliability, performance, and function test cases for RedHat OpenStack. I already looked at the **Tempest test**. but I'm asking if there's any other test I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you mention that you've already looked at Tempest, but I would strongly encourage you to take a second look. I understand that the documentation is a little underwhelming and tailoring the tempest configuration to your deployment can be a significant time investment. Beyond its documentation, it's a well-maintained OpenStack project and running sanity checks doesn't take too long to configure. The results can be truly revealing.

#### Create a tempest workspace and conduct sanity checks with `--smoke` or `-s`

Create a workspace with `tempest init myworkspace`. This will create the directory structure for you based off of what exists in /etc/tempest. If you've already configured your /etc/tempest, you're a step ahead, otherwise, you'll need to configure your myworkspace/etc/tempest.conf before running any test.

Once your workspace is configured for your deployment, execute `tempest run --smoke` from the workspace directory. This will execute ~100 smoke tests for basic cloud functionality and sanity testing. With my modest deployment, this doesn't take more than 3-5 minutes to get some worthwhile results.

#### Results from `--subunit`

Continuing with the myworkspace directory, running your smoketests with the `--subunit` flag (`tempest run --smoke --subunit`) produces the html-exportable subunit docs at `workspace/.stestr/$iteration` where `$iteration` is a 0-indexed iteration of `tempest run` you've executed.

For example, after your first iteration, run `subunit2html .stestr/0` to generate a well-formatted `results.html` for your review.

#### Beyond Smoketesting

If you start here and iterate, I think it naturally progresses into running the full gamut of tests. The workflow is a bit different from the smoke testing:

1. Generally start with `tempest cleanup --init-saved-state` which will produce a pre-test state of your cloud, a veritable snapshot of the resources you **do not** want to cleanup in post. The state is stored at saved_state.json.
2. Run your tests with options tailored to your deployment, most basically `tempest run`.
3. After analyzing your results, a run of `tempest cleanup` will destroy resources that do not exists in the saved_state.json file.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @mburling. I will follow your instructions as mentioned in your answer. I will feed you back with my finding.